# linking one component to another in react with if else condition. (without react-router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react, i am trying to link another page with if the condition is true
My code is like this

```
     checkCred(){


    for(var i=0; i < details_array.length; i++){
        var currentObject = details_array[i];
        if (this.email.value === currentObject.username){
            console.log('yes done it');
           // link to another component named as Index. if the above statement is true then only
           //
           }
        else{
       //Sorry your credentials were wrong
          }


       }
   }
```

here is button which is connected to this link.

```
       <span onClick={this.checkCred.bind(this)} className="button1" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" > BLOCK </span>
```

I dont know how to connect to another page, when i am using react-router. it is directly going to another page without checking condition.

Comment: Can you post your route settings (e.g. your route container if you have any)? And does the 'yes done it' shown in the console ? A note if you are not aware: If you use chrome you can select the Preserve Log checkbox in the chorme console to retain any log even though the page may have redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus problem can be solved by {withRouter}
Code will look like this.

```
          for(var i=0; i < details_array.length; i++){
        var currentObject = details_array[i];
        if (this.email.value == currentObject.username && this.password.value == currentObject.password){
            console.log('yes done it');

            this.props.router.push('Index');

        }
```

I hope this will help everyone!!!

Thanks